# Почему не работает регистронезависимость регулярного выражения в php?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не работает регистронезависимость (флаг i) в регулярном выражении после переноса на новый хостинг. Кодировка windows-1251.

И текст и файл в нужной кодировке. Какой-то настройки не хватает на сервере?

```
$text = 'что-то написано ТЕКСТ что-то написано';
echo preg_replace('#текст#si', '', $text);
// выводит оригинальную строку из $text, ничего не вырезано


$text = 'что-то написано ТЕКСТ что-то написано';
echo preg_replace('#ТЕКСТ#si', '', $text);
// выводит строку с вырезанным ТЕКСТ.
```

Хоть флаг i указан, регулярка реагирует на регистр символов. Почему?

Comment: можно любой символ использовать, / как один из вариантов. Я хочу #

Comment: Еще надо флаг `u`

Comment: флаг UTF для кодировки windows-1251?

Comment: Посмотрите вопросы в [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php) - там везде указывают флаги после / в конце выражения - это стандарт.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov тут тоже флаги указаны в конце выражения, после разделителя, в данном случае - `#`

Comment: Чтобы закончить холивар на счет разделителей, вот ссылка на доку https://www.php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Answer (score 2):

В итоге решилось установкой локали на сервере.

На старом сервере `locale -a` выдавало много локалей разных, там где-то и cp1251 наверно есть.
На новом сервере `locale -a` выдавало только 3 штуки и все utf-8.

В файле /etc/locale.gen раскомментировал ru_RU.cp1251, после выполнил команду `locale-gen`

Команда `locale -a` вывела в списке и ru-RU.CP1251. После всё заработало, setlocale в php не добавлял, флаги не менял, php вообще не трогал

Answer (score 1):

В итоге получается вот что - чтобы найти регистро-независимую UTF-8 строку нужно добавить u флаг (как и сказал @u_mulder). Для того чтобы найти строку того же регистра флаг добавлять не нужно так как идёт сравнение символов 1-в-1, в то время как в регистро-независимом сравнении этого не получится, так как код конвертирует текст в ASCII (?) кодировку и приведет к нижнему регистру, не найдя нужных совпадений для замещения.

```
 <?php
 $text = 'что-то написано ТЕКСТ что-то написано';
 echo preg_replace('#текст#usi', '', $text); // Заместит с /u флагом

 $text = 'что-то написано ТЕСТ что-то написано';
 echo preg_replace('#ТЕСТ#si', '', $text); // Заместит 1-к-1
```

Comment: ничего он не менял ни с флагом `u` ни без него. Кодировка текста и программы windows-1251